# Swift: Set<Object> fundamental operations result in copies or pointers?

Tags: swift

I'm currently looking for some reference, outside apple's swift programming reference for the memory space of Set types and resulting fundamental operations (union, intersection, exclusion, subtraction etc)

Given the below pseudo code:

```
var entities = Set<GKEntity>()
var subSetA = Set<GKEntity>()
var subSetB = Set<GKEntity>()
```

Each subset will have a subclass of GKEntity which will be called on some routines I will use elswhere in my application.

When I use the union of these subsets, IE: I will have set as the superset of all subsets, or the union of all subsets.

Does this mean that the superset will be a copy of the elements in the subset or will they be pointers only?

I ask this for memory space usage as if the operation requires copying or allocating new memory adresses, I will need to use a different strategy of storing my elements.

From a purely structural standpoint, I assume these will be "shallow" copies meaning they will be pointers to memory adresses, but once I have created the superset as the union of all subsets, I want any removal or addition to be reflected on the superset, or down on the particular subset if the operation is made on the superset.

Hope this question is valid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note, I'm assuming you mean [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GameplayKit/Reference/GKEntity_Class/) `GKEntity`.

Since `GKEntity` is a class, the sets you created will store references (pointers) to those actual `GKEntity` objects. So any changes to the objects in a subset will be reflected in the superset.

Here is a short piece of code that demonstrates this:

```
class A: IntegerLiteralConvertible, Hashable, CustomStringConvertible {
    var x: Int

    required init(integerLiteral value: Int) {
        self.x = value
    }

    var hashValue: Int {
        return x
    }

    var description: String {
        return String(x)
    }
}

func ==(lhs: A, rhs: A) -> Bool {
    return lhs.hashValue == rhs.hashValue
}

let setA: Set<A> = [1, 2, 3, 4]
let setB: Set<A> = [5, 6, 7, 8]
print(setA) // [2, 3, 1, 4]
print(setB) // [5, 6, 7, 8]
let union = setA.union(setB)
print(union) // [2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 3, 1, 8]
setA.first!.x = 30
print(union) // [30, 4, 5, 6, 7, 3, 1, 8]
```

As you can see, I made a change (changed `x` from 2 to 30) to the first item in `setA`. Then I printed out `union`, which did contain a 30 in it.

Comment: Ok, concise.It seems the GKEntity class conformance on the link you posted does not include Hashable but it's present in the xcode documentation. So this means it goes both ways? super set operations reflect on subsets? It won't make life harder if not, but just asking to complete the understanding

Comment: Since the sets store references of `GKEntity`s, it goes both ways. Why not try it yourself using the code I've given? It's going to be fun! @triple7

Comment: Perhaps worth explicitly mentioning (for future readers of this answer) that sets are non-ordered collections, which is the reason that the _"first item in `setA`"_ happens to be `2` (which could be confusing as it is the 2nd item added to the set in the definition of the set).